# Change name of app depending on language?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I know how to change the App name in WMAppManifest.xml, but how can I change it depending on the current language? Here is the code I tried, but it does not work:

```
<App xmlns="" ProductID="{}" **Title="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.Name, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"** RuntimeType="Silverlight" Version="1.1.0.0" Genre="apps.normal" Author="Fehlerquotient author" Description="" Publisher="Christian" PublisherID="{}">
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "don't works".

Comment: I've only ever done WP7, but if I recall the app name is fixed / culture invariant. For example, Facebook is Facebook regardless of what culture you are in.

Answer (score 0):

Open the AppResources.resx file where you can set the application title, desired resource language as (name,value) pair.

you can bind in your xml file as below:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.ApplicationTitle}, Source={StaticResource LocalizedString}}"
Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"
Margin="10.0"/>
```

To work as you expect, do the following: 
right click on your project and select properties. select your desired supported culture. save the file. A dialogue box will appear with a message, select 'yes' in the dialogue.

After saving the file, a new AppResources file will be created. For example, if you select Spanish language in the culture. Then resource file name will be like AppResources.es.resx file. When you open the file, you will see that selected language as the value of the ResourceLanguage. You will use the 'name' of the resource file in your xml file to get the desired value. Name will be used as the token programmatically and value will be displayed to the end user.

Run your app and change the language in the setting page. Restart your phone emulator. run your app again. you will see your newly assigned language.

For more information about localizing your application, you can check the following link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff637520(v=vs.105).aspx

Hope this helps,
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not what I was looking for. I mean the Application Title in the App List(where all the apps are).